# CSS : Fixed sliding form pushed up when android soft keyboard is opened in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am facing this issue on mobile browser. I have one sliding contact us form which is fixed it left bottom of page. When I clicks it, sliding form is opened. But when I clicks on input field to type, android keypad gets opened which pushes fixed contact us form to upside which goes outside of viewport. So i can not see focused field to type.
I need to show fixed form behind keyboard with scrollbar to form so that I can see all input fields as well as submit button.
The css I have used is as follows,

```
#contact {                        //main div, which opens contact us sliding form
position: fixed;
z-index: 99;
left: 0;
bottom: 0px;
height: 350px;
margin-left: -3px;
margin-bottom: -3px;
```

}

```
#contact-form {                  //main form which has input fields
/*float: left;*/
width: 225px;
height: 100%;
z-index: 99;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 3px;
background-clip: 'padding-box';
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
```

}

Comment: I assume you are using cordova/phonegap, Refer this :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132422/phonegap-android-soft-keyboard-covers-input-fields    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575999/input-field-hidden-when-soft-keyboard-appears-in-phonegap

Comment: No I am not using cordove/phonegap. I am developing webisite. And need to load website in mobile browser.